# Replace a value in a dataframe by using other matching IDs of another dataframe in R

Tags: r, linux, dataframe, match

So I have a problem in R to update values in the main data frame by using a second data frame, plus matching IDs.

So here is the data files demos:
First the main data I have like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"),
                  year = 2000:2005, status = c("0","1","0","0","1","1"))

 ID year status
 A1 2000    0
 A2 2001    1
 B1 2002    0
 B2 2003    0
 C1 2004    1
 C2 2005    1
```

And second data, that I want to replace "status" values into the main data.

```
df2 = data.frame(ID = c("A1", "B2","C1"), status = c("1", "1", "0"))

 ID status
 A1    1
 B2    1
 C1    0
```

Finally desired ouput is like this:

```
 ID year status
 A1 2000    1
 A2 2001    1
 B1 2002    0
 B2 2003    1
 C1 2004    0
 C2 2005    1
```

As you can see, status column is updated with the second data right now.
Well, I have tried merge/left join and I couldn't get a solution, some part of the data updated, some part not.

The solutions were given here, mostly for the datasets where the second one is bigger than the first dataset, which I had lots of NAs in the end as you can guess.

Also tried this code:

```
df1$status[df1$id %in% df2$id] <- df2$status
```

Result was the same.
So If you can help me where the problem is (whether something should be muted or mutated), that would be great.

Comment: I think you missed capitals in `df1$status[df1$id %in% df2$id] <- df2$status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1$status[df1$ID %in% df2$ID] <- df2$status[df2$ID %in% df1$ID]
```

What about this? You only have to fill the condition in the assignment

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but it happened again, it doesn't work in the example data above.There is no replacing in the values.

Comment: `ID year status
1 A1 2000      1
2 A2 2001      1
3 B1 2002      0
4 B2 2003      1
5 C1 2004      0
6 C2 2005      1`      I'm obtaining this output..

Comment: Sorry, I meant that It doesn't work on my real data as in the hypothetical data above. It does indeed work the data created above.